# How to make Excel increment by a large number (I want the values of cells D4,D100,D196,D292, etc)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have ~35000 data points, and I want to sum data points 4-99,100-195,196-291, etc. So basically I want 365 sums of 96 data points each.

I managed to use the IF function logic to print the sums I want in cells D4, D100, D196, etc, and 0 everywhere else. But I can't view those easily without scrolling through thousands of data points. I thought Excel could figure out if I plugged in a few values that I want to increment by 96, but it must be too big and it's confused.

How can I get the 365 sums in a nice column by themselves?

Comment: Filter on column D and choose to only display non-zero values?

Comment: Would a filter display the nonzero values in rows 1-365? Or would there be blank spaces in between? (I have never used a filter so first I would have to learn how to do it)

Comment: The row numbers would be as they should be. The other rows would just be hidden. See [How to Use the Custom AutoFilter on an Excel Table](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-custom-autofilter-on-an-excel-table.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
="D" & 96*ROW()-92 & ":D" & 96*ROW()+3
```

and copy down and in **A1** enter:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]